# Heat equation with one end insulated and other end at $100^\circ C$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am solving the following problem-

> At $t=0$, a rod of length $2$ meter is maintained at $0^\circ C$. At $t>0$, the left end is insulated whereas the right end is maintained at $100^\circ C$. Now solve for the time dependent temperature equation.

Clearly, the Initial condition is $u(x,0)=0$ and the boundary conditions are
$$
\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0}=0$$ and $$u(2,t)=100
$$

I proceed to use separation of variables. Clearly $X=c_1\cos(kx)+c_2\sin(kx)$ and $T=e^{-\alpha^2k^2t}$. From the first boundary condition, clearly $c_2=0$. Thus, $u=X(x)T(t)=c_1\cos(kx)e^{-\alpha^2k^2t}$.

Now, I can't proceed from here and have no idea how to use the second BC.

How to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say you should not expect a classical solution to exist since the initial data is piecewise defined: $u(x,0) = 0$ if $x\in[0,2)$ and $u(x,0)=100$ if $x=2$. Maybe using Fourier analysis you find a solution.